# Reflect the class file changes without bouncing websphere server

Tags: java, websphere-7

I'm using multiple EAR's in WAS7 server. For each and every changes in my class file I need to bounce the server. Is there any way to reflect my code chages without bouncing the WAS7 server? I looked into the thread [Best to way to re-load java classes without WebSphere re-start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359065/best-to-way-to-re-load-java-classes-without-websphere-re-start). But I not clear about that tutorial. Can somebody help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for Hot deployment and dynamic reloading of applications on websphere. Here is the documentation that should guide to achieve that:

[Websphere Hot deployment and dynamic reloading](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_app_hotupgrade.html)

Comment: Yes. I always used to hot deploy my files(class files) for testing purposes. The one in which you told, the 6th point finally mentioned that we need to restart the server. I am new to java environment. I couldn't understand the things that are mentioned in that page. Could you please tell me in simple manner to understand that or to fix my issue?
Thanks in advance